# Laplace transform of a function defined by integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, laplace-transform

I have a function of the form $f(u) = ke^{-au}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{z-1}(1+x)^{-z-1}e^{-bxu}dx$ where $a,b,u,z>0$ are all real positive numbers and $k$ is a positive normalization factor. I need to calculate the Laplace transform of $f(u)$. We have

$$F(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(u)e^{-su}du = k\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-au} \left(\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{z-1}(1+x)^{-z-1}e^{-bxu}dx\right) e^{-su} du$$

Since Fobini's theorem holds (Does it really hold?) we can change the order of integration

$$F(s) = k\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{z-1}(1+x)^{-z-1}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(a+s+bx)u}du\right) dx= k\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{z-1}(1+x)^{-z-1}}{a+s+bx} dx $$

I can't go any further! What should I do next? Also I'm contemplating the change of integration order, is it valid and correct?!? What about the region of convergence for Laplace transform, how to find it?

Thanks in advance!

==============================Corrections=============================
The values that $z$ can assume are positive real numbers $z>0$ however if integral diverges, then we can restrict it to other values!

Comment: How $z$ is defined? At a first glance both functions ($f(u), F(s)$) have problems at $x=0, \,1$

Comment: Thank you for this comment! Wow, sorry but I literally forgot to mention $z$ which is ridiculous! I added the $z>0$. Also the sign of $1-x$ was wrong and was corrected!

Comment: Making the substitution $\,\frac x{1+x}=t\quad F(s)=\int_0^1\frac{t^{z-1}}{(a+s)(1-t)+bt}dt\,$. I'm not sure about a nice closed form...

Comment: @Svyatoslav thanks for the hint! Any well known special function would suffice too! How about region of convergence? I don't know how to characterize it since the term $bx$ is not constant inside integral!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to use $$ _2F_1(a,b;c; z)=\frac{1}{B(b,c-b)}\int_0^1\frac{x^{b-1}(1-x)^{c-b-1}}{(1-xz)^a}dx$$ by a suitable change of variable. Your $a$ can be taken as $0$ without loss of generality.

Comment: Yes indeed, thank you! Unfortunately I have to use the Kummer functions and their Laplace transform, that's the only way!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see Kummer functions. From the Svatovslav presention we get at least  formally

$$F(s)=\frac{1}{a+s}\times B(z,z+1)\ _2F_1(1,z;z+1; 1-\frac{b}{a+s}).$$ Discussion when $z$ is not a positive number seems complicated.

Comment: $f(u) = ke^{-au}\Gamma\left( z \right) U\left(z,0,bu\right)$ where $U(a,b,x)$ is the confluent hypergeometric function of the second kind. Then we can use the equation 13.10.7 given in NIST-DLMF to find the Laplace transform.

Comment: BTW can you please  explain how did you solved it directly?!

Comment: Well, you apply the above Euler formula to $a=1$, $b=z$ and $c=z+1$ The denominator $(a+s)(1-t)+bt$ has not the desired form for $(1-zt)$, but just write it out as $(a+s)(1-t(1-\frac{b}{a+s})).$ Also I told you that you could take $a=0$ without loss of generality. Why? because if $g_1(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $g(u)$ then the Laplace transform of $e^{-au}g(u)$ is $g_1(s+a).$